# Trying to clean up object keys in lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

So I have an array of objects that comes in like:

```
var arr = [{'name of something ': 'value', 'another key': 'another value', ...}];
```

So I wrote this function:

```
function _cleanUpObjectKeys(data) {
  return data.forEach(function(dataObject){
    return lodash.forOwn(dataObject, function(value, key){
      lodash.trim(key);
      lodash.snakeCase(key);
      console.log(key);
    });
  });
```

Hoping it would take an array like the one I showed you can give me back:

```
var arr = [{'name_of_something': 'value', 'another_key': 'another value', ...}];
```

But alas it doesn't. **Help?**

The `console.log(key)` spits out:

- `name of something` (with trailing space)
- `another key`

*Essentially I want to remove all trailing spaces from the keys and convert them to snake case.*

Comment: you need to return `data.map`, `.forEach` doesn't return a new array.

Comment: @Daniel_L That still didn't work.

Comment: looks like `_.forOwn` isn't doing what you expected it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and lodash's [`transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#transform) function for this:

```
function _cleanUpObjectKeys(data) {
  return data.map(function(dataObject){
    return _.transform(dataObject, function(resultObject, value, key) {
      const newKey = _.snakeCase(_.trim(key));
      resultObject[newKey] = value;
    });
  });
}
```

[Working CodePen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/VPzgRV?editors=1010)

Answer (score 4):

You could compose a [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) iteratee function as follows:

```
_.map(arr, _.unary(_.partialRight(
  _.mapKeys,
  _.flow(_.trim, _.snakeCase)
)));
```

- [unary()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unary) makes sure only one argument is passed, in this case, the key
- [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight) provides the iteratee function for `mapKeys()`
- [mapKeys()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys) returns a new object with mapped keys
- [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow) creates a new function, chaining together input and output for the functions passed to it